# How to call a method of a class A inside class A?

Tags: javascript, ajax, recursion, this

I need to call method getData() inside my AJAX again, if 401 occurs and counter is lower or equal 1. The problem is, that the method is not called in that 401 status... How can I call that method inside the same class?

```
export default class Search {
    constructor(){
        this.result = {};
    }

      getData(callback, url){
        var counter = 0;
        alert("GET DATA CALLED " + counter);
        $.ajax({
            'url': proxy + url,
            'type': 'GET',
            'content-Type': 'x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'dataType': 'json',
            'headers': {
              'Authorization': 'bearer ' + localStorage.access_token
            },
            'success': function (result) {
              documentView.fillDocuments(result);
              callback(result);
            },  
            'error': function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          //    alert('Error: ' + errorThrown);
              console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status + ' ' + 
                  XMLHttpRequest.statusText);
              return "";
            }, statusCode: {
              401: function (response) {
                counter++;
                alert("401");
                if(counter <= 1){
                  refreshToken(); // CALLED
                  getData(callback, url); // NOT CALLED
                } 
              }
            }
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of regular function expressions is creating a new scope for 'this', you can circumnavigate this by using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Something like below... untested.

```
export default class Search {
    constructor() {
        this.result = {};
    }

    getData = (callback, url) => {
        var counter = 0;
        alert("GET DATA CALLED " + counter);
        $.ajax({
            url: proxy + url,
            type: "GET",
            "content-Type": "x-www-form-urlencoded",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                Authorization: "bearer " + localStorage.access_token
            },
            success: (result) => {
                documentView.fillDocuments(result);
                callback(result);
            },
            error: (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                //    alert('Error: ' + errorThrown);
                console.log(
                    XMLHttpRequest.status + " " + XMLHttpRequest.statusText
                );
                return "";
            },
            statusCode: {
                401: (response) => {
                    counter++;
                    alert("401");
                    if (counter <= 1) {
                        refreshToken(); // CALLED
                        this.getData(callback, url); // NOT CALLED - Should be called now.
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what your code says to do. Every time you call getData, you're setting counter to 0 (var counter = 0). Thus when the function is called again, counter will get set to 0. You could put counter on the Search class, e.g. this.counter. This is now out of scope of your question though :) Please upvote and accept if it was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`this.getData(callback, url)` - to call the method inside the class.

But you need to replace all function declaration `function () {}` by arrow function `() => {}` inside the `getData()` method